# Convert this to Realtime Ajax

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a single page that successfully does xmlhttprequest, but I would like same stuff in Ajax format.

What the page does is that it calculates two values with the use of 3 different operators in the select box.

**Here is the code: CalcServ.php**

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <title>Calculator</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calc()
{

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  val1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  val2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  mani = document.getElementById("manipulator").value;

  if (val1 != "" && val2 != "")
  {

  document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML="Calculating...";
  queryPath = "CalcServ.php?value1="+val1+"&value2="+val2+"&manipulator="+mani;

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

      document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET",queryPath);
  xmlhttp.send();

  }
}

</script>

  </head>
        <body>
            <div width="320">
            <center>
            <form>
                <font size="4"><strong>PHP/AJAX Calculator</strong></font><br><br>
                <input onkeypress="return onlyNumbers()" onkeyup="calc()" id="value1" type="text" name="value1"><br>
                <select onchange="calc()" id="manipulator" name="manipulator">
                    <option value="add">SUM</option>
                    <option value="subtract">SUBTRACT</option>
                    <option value="multiply">MULTIPLY</option>
                    <option value="divide">DIVIDE</option>
                </select><br>
                <input id="value2" onkeyup="calc()" type="text" name="value2">

            </form>

          <strong><font size="4" color="blue"><span id="resp" title="This is generated via an AJAX/PHP call"></span></font></strong>
          <br>
          <br>

    </center>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Thanks for going through.

Comment: Can't you use jQuery?

Comment: Yeah! Ok, but how can I then convert it to jquery